# Cycling tabs graphically

Tags: macos, mac, tabs, window-manager

Mac OS X's window manager is composed of:

1. Applications
2. Windows
3. Tabs

By default on OS X, you can cycle over applications with the famous `⌘⇥` shortcut. In addition to this, I use a little utility called [Witch](http://www.manytricks.com/witch) which enables cycling (graphically) over windows too(I've defined it on `⌥⇥`). Unfortunately, it does not currently support tabs cycling...

Would you have any suggestion for this? I know I already can `^⇥` for this, but I'm looking for a graphical utility where you are not blind during cycling.

Thank you.

Comment: what about exposé (F3) ? Or is that not what you define as `tab cycling`?

Comment: @ChristopheD: I think he means switching between Safari tabs...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, more of a proof of concept that it could be done. Using AppleScript (via the "Script Editor" application in /Applications/AppleScript) I am able to get a list of the names of the tabs in the frontmost window of Safari:

```
tell application "Safari"
    get the name of every tab of window 1
end tell
```

Produces:

```
{"Unanswered Questions - Super User", "How do I install a font on a Macintosh? - Super User", "Cycling tabs graphically - Super User"}
```

And the following:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to tab 3
    end tell
end tell
```

Make the third tab of the first window active. So given this, it would be possible to write some sort of script or application which pops up a list of tabs to choose from and then based on selection, activates the current tab. I don't know of any software like that, if anyone else does, please post!